# Grep: Why escape modifiers?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

By modifiers I mean the following:

```
-\{m\} exactly m repetitions of previous character
- \{m,\} at least m repetitions of previous character
- \{m,n\} any number of repetitions of prev char between m and n inclusive
- \< beginning of word
- \> end of word
```

what is the reason for escaping them?

For example if there is a word "cat" inside file1:

```
$ egrep -n '\<cat\>' file1
17:cat
```

The above command finds the word "cat" but what about the below command, it returns nothing but what is it actually doing?

```
$ egrep -n '<cat>' file1
```

Comment: Presumably to allow you to search for actual less-than and greater-than signs in text?

Comment: what special meaning does < > have in bash aside from regex word match? Also they patterns are inside single quotes don't they turn off special meaning, why escape then?

Comment: They are redirection operators. The single quotes keep the shell from interpreting them as redirections.

Comment: so why escape when already inside single quote which turns off the redirection meaning?

Comment: So that egrep sees them as special tokens instead of just < or >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the earliest versions of `grep` didn't recognize
`{…}`, `?`, `+`, `(…)`, `<`, and `>` as meta-characters —
they just matched themselves. 
The only meta-characters were `[…]`, `^`, `$`, `.`, `*`, and `\`. 
This behavior was kept for backward compatibility
(so that old scripts would still work the way they did
without needing to be rewritten). 
Therefore, you have to use `\` to activate the special properties
of these more recently invented meta-characters,
just as `n` and `t` don't mean newline and tab (they mean `n` and `t`);
you need to use `\n` and `\t` to get newline and tab.